# How to send a message to a bot from another app

Tags: c#, botframework

I have an App that user can ask help to other people and I'm developing a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework V4 to interact with those users.

What I want is when a user asks help for another user the Bot message another user warning that someone is waiting for help.

I have searched for an example of how I could do that, and I haven't found any.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking to send a proactive message. You can find documentation here:
[Get notification from bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Code sample here:
[ProactiveBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/ProactiveBot.cs)

How to send message to other/multiple participants here:
[Send and receive activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-connector?view=azure-bot-service-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: "an App that user can ask help to other people": that's not proactive here, because the OP wants to notify a "new" user

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and i have a doubt. The other App has it UserId. Do you have an idea how i can link this Id with the ConversationId to send correctly the proactive message?

Comment: @RenatoRamosNascimento I've added link to documentation that I think it will help for sending messages.

Comment: @lonut That links is about V3 documentation, I'm using V4. I know how to send messages, my problem is I want to send a message from an app outside the web server that my bot is hosted. Thank you for the attention